# Actionscript 3: Rotate multiple shapes around internal point

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, rotation, shapes

I'm having trouble with AS3 which I have to use for a little research project of mine.

The AS3 project would create a number of randomly placed squares which all would rotate around its center point.

I managed to figure out how to rotate it internally using [this handy walkthrough](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/rotation/).

However I am having trouble applying this method to all squares which were created in a for loop with randomly selected stage points. Only the first created will rotate

Here is the code in question:-

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    var square:Shape = new Shape();
    this.addChild(square);
    var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth) + 50;
    var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight) + 50;
    square.x=posX;
    square.y=posY;
    var curSquareAng:Number=0;
    var squareRotCenter:Point=new Point(0,0);
    drawShapes();
    var squareMat:Matrix=square.transform.matrix.clone();
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);

function onEnter(e:Event):void {
    curSquareAng = (curSquareAng+2)%360;
    rotateSquare(curSquareAng);
}

function rotateSquare(deg:Number):void {
    var mat:Matrix= squareMat.clone();  
    MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint(mat,squareRotCenter.x, squareRotCenter.y, deg);
    square.transform.matrix = mat;
}
```

I realize I likely have to create an array for each of the squares initial center points and loop through them. However I am completely lost on how to do so. As you can likely tell I am unfamiliar with AS3 and would much appreciate any help you can give this beginner programmer. :P

Comment: just add all squares to one container and rotate the container

Comment: But that wouldn't rotate each square by its center point but instead rotate all squares around the screen.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko I have first read the question as you did, but no, he is using *internal* rotation points, these differ per square by default.

Comment: Sorry if I did not explain myself well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own class based on a shape, then you stuff it full of properties that represent rotation center point, current angle and whatever else you'd want your squares to contain, then give the class `update` method which will do what you wrote in `onEnter` function for itself only. Then you will have easier control over what your squares are able to do. This technique is called "encapsulation".

On a side note, if you're wanting your square to rotate around internal point of (0,0), you can set their `rotation` property to achieve the desired effect. For other points, the walkthrough or its equivalent should be used.

```
public class Square extends Shape {
    public var rotationCenter:Point=new Point();
    private var currentAngle:Number=0;
    public var rotationSpeed:Number=2; // degrees per frame
    private var baseMatrix:Matrix;
    public function Square() {
        // draw the shape on "this.graphics"
        this.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00,1);
        this.graphics.moveTo(-20,-20);
        this.graphics.lineTo(20,-20);
        this.graphics.lineTo(20,20);
        this.graphics.lineTo(20,-20);
        this.graphics.lineTo(-20,-20);
        this.graphics.endFill();
        // if not set in declaration, set internal vars
        baseMatrix=this.transform.matrix; // likely identity matrix, but let's initialize anyway
    }
    public function storeMatrix():void {
        // you are positioning a square after you create it, so probably you want its new location to be transformed
        // that one's matrix will no longer be an identity, so go capture
        baseMatrix=this.transform.matrix;
    }
    public function update():void {
        // should be called once per frame
        currentAngle=(currentAngle+rotationSpeed)%360;
        var mat:Matrix= baseMatrix.clone();
        MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint(mat,rotationCenter.x, rotationCenter.y, currentAngle);
        this.transform.matrix = mat;
    }
}
```

Now, you will have to maintain an array of squares to make them rotate separately:

```
var squares:Array=[];
for (var i:int=0;i<10;i++) {
    var square:Square=new Square();
    var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth) + 50;
    var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight) + 50;
    square.x=posX;
    square.y=posY;
    // after you position, give it a rotation point
    square.rotationCenter.x=Math.random()*40-20;
    square.rotationCenter.y=Math.random()*40-20; // -20 to 20, should do for this example
    // now fix the position so your square will know that it should rotate 
    // its *current* transform matrix
    square.storeMatrix();
    // even if it's actually unchanged by changing X or Y
    // also, should you desire to scale some square, you should do that prior to calling this
    // now add the square to an array
    squares.push(square);
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnter);
function onEnter(e:Event):void {
    for (var i:int=0;i<squares.length;i++) squares[i].update();
    // simple, isn't it? Each square will know what to do.
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm gonna give this a good look tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying this now and I'm having some trouble with it. Where do you write the code for the second part of the code (the for loop) would that be in the same class? and also is deg in rotatearoundinternalpoint supposed to be replaced with current angle?

Comment: The for loop should be located in the main class, not in the `Square` class, because a square is a building block, and your main class is the building that should consist of blocks. About "deg" - yes, indeed, it's a copy&paste artifact.

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't go your route in the end but because of your input my code looks a lot cleaner and helped me reach the desired goal.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Thank you Vesper for putting me on the right track I've managed to solve my problem thanks to your input (not necessarily through your way but your input helped me get to the destination per say).

I think I was making it a little too complicated going though the matrix route and instead used a shape array to loop through the squares and add rotation. The solution I came to is a little simple but gets the job done.

```
    public var rotationSpeed:Number=2; // degrees per frame
    public var square:Array = new Array(  );
    public function Square() {

        for (var i:int=0;i<10;i++) {
            square[i] = new Shape();
            var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth) + 50;
            var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight) + 50;
            square[i].graphics.lineStyle();
            var rgb = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
            square[i].graphics.beginFill(rgb);
            // -50 determines where the spin will center from.
            square[i].graphics.drawRect(-50,-50,100,100);
            square[i].graphics.endFill();
            square[i].x = posX;
            square[i].y = posY;
            addChild(square[i]);
        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnter);
    }

    private function onEnter(e:Event):void {
        for (var i:int=0; i < square.length; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).rotation += rotationSpeed;
        }
    }
```